# Cannot install react-export-excel using npm in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am running : npm install react-export-excel --save

and I get the following error:

[image]

I receieved the same error while installing jspdf ( I can install certain other libraries successfully like file-saver, I could install a lower version of jspdf, i.e., 1.4).

This is my package.json file:

```
       {
      "name": "insurance_automation",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "config": "^3.1.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "js-xlsx": "^0.8.22",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "multer": "^1.4.1",
        "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
        "node": "^11.15.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.2.1",
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
        "react-pdf": "^4.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
        "sequelize": "^5.8.6",
        "universal-cookie": "^4.0.0",
        "xlsx": "^0.14.3"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "server": "nodemon server",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm start\" "
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
      }
    }
```

The node version is lower than 12 to send mails using nodemailer to support mail server using TLS v1.0 or below, I guess.

Comment: you need to show the full error. Seems like a problem with your git client

Comment: this is the complete error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install like this

```
npm install react-export-excel@0.5.2 --save
```

make sure you run with an administrator account or in Linux with `sudo`

you can try this package as well
https://github.com/react-csv/react-csv

Comment: I received the same error. I need to export data to excel file (report generation), any other alternatives? or any other lower versions of react-export-excel?

Comment: there are so many npm modules available you can test this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-excel-export

Comment: This is a NodeJS package, so I will have to render it to react later then, aren't there any ReactJS packages